# Javascript function to change link URL onclick with delay

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to change the a link element URL onclick, so I can track with a pixel. 
I'm trying to make the same code but with a 1 second delay to the old URL.

This is my script:

```
<script>
   function update_url(url) {
       history.pushState(null, null, url);
   }
</script>
```

At the link i'm using this one:

```
<a onclick="update_url('/mega-liquidacao');" href="#">
```

What I'm trying to do: Use this same code and after a 1 second delay go back to '/mega-liquidacao'.

Comment: so call it with settimeout....

Comment: With the above comment, I would like to add that avoid using inline javascript.

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval function

```
setInterval(function(){history.pushState(null, null, url);},1000);
```

Comment: Why `setInterval`? And that's an invalid syntax anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()`:

```
function update_url(url) {
    setTimeout(function(){
         history.pushState(null, null, url);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: It Works thanks! But, how i aply this only to the second URL? 
The timeline I'm trying is like this :
Click ->UPDATE TO URL X -> 1 Sec -> UPDATE TO URL Y 
I'm trying to do this so i can track the click action on my pixel withou the user have an 404 error.

Comment: There is only one URL passed to the function. You have to add another parameter to pass the second URL. Then use the first URL before the `setTimeout()` and the second URL inside it.

Comment: It was easier than I thought, sorry for asking something this easy, I'm new to javascript. It solves like this: 
<a onclick="update_url('/mega-liquidacao/barra'); setTimeout(function(){ update_url('/mega-liquidacao/'); }, 1000);">